# Wordpress site with timer that works in preview but not when published

Tags: preview, wordpress

I have a timer script (see it working standalone at http://pointy-end.com/timer/timer.php)
that I have copy/pasted into customloop.php.  It works fine when the post is previewed, but when published it's no longer possible to select a time (3,5,10 minutes) to kickstart it.
I'm a newbie, and I can't figure out why this would work in preview but not when published.

I've disabled all my plugins (except for Single Post Template, Jetpack by WordPress.com,PHP Code for posts & WP Super Cache.
You can see it NOT working at http://pointy-end.com/image-writing-prompt-may-24/

I'd REALLY appreciate some help.  Thanks guys, Cheryl

Comment: Hi Cheryl, Ithink im facing a similar issue with some script generated outputs (charts) are displayed in preview mode but not after publishing the page/post (wordpress.org by the way). Im curious to know wether you have ever figured this out or not, thank you